# How to show p-value and axis value correctly in R?

Tags: r, p-value, article

trying to submit an article with statistical data and figures. I like R and used it for that. I wrote this one

```
graph_a=
  ggplot(df, aes(x = group, y = squareBowmansCapsule, fill = isInfected)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  xlab(label = "Groups") +
  ylab(label = "Bowman's capsule area sq.µm") +
  scale_fill_discrete(name = "") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 10),axis.title.x = element_text(size = 10)) +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(size = 10),axis.title.y = element_text(size = 10))+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank())+
  labs (title = "Bowman's capsule area") +
  theme(legend.position = c(0.1, 1),
        legend.direction = "vertical")

graph_a1 = graph_a +
  annotate(
    "text",
    x = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
    y = -1.5,
    label = c("Control", "1 group", "2 group", "3 group")
  )
graph_a_with_pValue1=add_pval(graph_a1, 
                 pairs = list(c(1, 2),c(1,3),c(1,4)
                 ),
                 test='kruskal.test',heights=c(14000,16000,18500))
```

and got the figure like this: [figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HRFrt.png)

editors remarks were:
*1 Please use commas to separate thousands for numbers with five or more digits (not four digits) in the picture, e.g., “10000” should be “10,000”.
2.Please change the terms into scientific notations in the figure, e.g., “2 × 10−16”, not “2e−16”.
3.Please change P in lower case.*

I solved the problem  with the following steps

1. manually show in each figure the needed scale with this code

```
scale_y_continuous(labels = c("0", "5000", "10,000", "15,000", "20,000"))
```

then, mannualy added annotations

```
pval_annotations =  c("'p = 2 × 10⁻¹³'",
                      "'p < 2 × 10⁻¹⁶'",
                      "'p = 4.7 × 10⁻¹¹'")

graph_a_with_pValue = add_pval(
  graph_a1,
  textsize = 8,
  annotation = pval_annotations,
  pairs = list(c(1, 2), c(1, 3), c(1, 4)),
  heights = c(14000, 16000, 18500)
)
```

finally, I got this code

```
graph_a =
  ggplot(df, aes(x = group, y = squareBowmansCapsule, fill = isInfected)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  xlab(label = "Groups") +
  ylab(label = "Bowman's capsule area sq.µm") +
  scale_fill_discrete(name = "") +
  theme(
    axis.text.x = element_text(size = 12, face = "bold"),
    axis.title.x = element_text(size = 14, face = "bold")
  ) +
  theme(
    axis.text.y = element_text(size = 12, face = "bold"),
    axis.title.y = element_text(size = 14, face = "bold")
  ) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = c("0", "5000", "10,000", "15,000", "20,000")) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank()) +
  labs (title = "Bowman's capsule area") +
  theme(legend.position = c(0.1, 1),
        legend.direction = "vertical")



graph_a1 = graph_a +
  annotate(
    "text",
    x = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
    y = -1.5,
    label = c("Control", "1 group", "2 group", "3 group")
  )

pval_annotations =  c("'p = 2 × 10⁻¹³'",
                      "'p < 2 × 10⁻¹⁶'",
                      "'p = 4.7 × 10⁻¹¹'")


graph_a_with_pValue = add_pval(
  graph_a1,
  textsize = 8,
  annotation = pval_annotations,
  pairs = list(c(1, 2), c(1, 3), c(1, 4)),
  heights = c(14000, 16000, 18500)
)
```

and that figure[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4sI8I.png)

My question is: how to get the same result without so much effort?

Comment: The `scales` package can help with two of those (commas in numbers, scientific notation): https://scales.r-lib.org/

Comment: For your axis labels you could do `scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::label_comma())`

Comment: it does not work @stefan, because it makes comma in 5000 as well, but editor said only 5 digit numbers should be separated by the comma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two helper functions, both using `scales::` as a starter:

```r
mycomma <- function(z) {
  out <- scales::label_comma()(z)
  sub("^([0-9]),([0-9]{3})$", "\\1\\2", out)
}
myscientific <- function(z) {
  out <- scales::label_scientific()(z)
  out <- parse(text = sub("e", "%*% 10^", out))
  out[abs(z) < 1e-99] <- "0" # otherwise we see "0 x 10^+0"
  out
}
```

The use of `abs(z) < 1e-99` may be sensitive to your actual data. The intent of that vice `z == 0` is to work around [Why are these numbers not equal?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9508518/3358272) (and [R FAQ 7.31](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f)), especially knowing we're dealing with high-precision near-zero numbers. With this sample data (in my hasty testing), it worked as close to zero as `abs(z) < 1e-323`, while `1e-324` showed `0 x 10^+0`.

Sample data:

```r
dat <- data.frame(x=seq(2000, 15000, length.out = 5), y=seq(2e-10, 2e-5, length.out = 5))
```

A plot, using our two helper functions in the `labels=` argument for each axis:

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dat, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_continuous(labels = mycomma) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = myscientific)
```

[image: ggplot with custom scientific and comma labelling]

Comment: I was about to submit a PR to the `scales` repo for the scientific notation when I saw that it had already been done as [PR #220](https://github.com/r-lib/scales/pull/220) ... then ignored for 2 years and closed by the author.